# How to automatically remove container data from the host when rm the container?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I find that if running `docker run -d -v /HOST/PATH:/CONTAINER/PATH IMAGE` to mount data volumes, the data still remains on the host after deleting the container.
Is it designed to do so? Is there a way to automatically remove container data from the host when deleting the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manage data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/):

> Data volumes are designed to persist data, independent of the container’s lifecycle.

If you don't want the data to persist on the host, don't use volumes.